# Identifiers missing in function prototype

Tags: c, struct

I am reading about socket programming done in Unix via C one of the function that is particularly interesting to me just because of the syntax that it uses -:

```
int  pr_usrreq(struct socket *so , int req, struct mbuf  *m0 , *m1 , *m2);
```

The above example is taken from this [link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-tcpsystemcalls/index.html).

What it is interesting is that how is this valid C syntax ?

Shouldn't there be an identifier after `struct mbuf  *m0 , *m1 , *m2` for `*m1`and `*m2` ?

Or this is just an erroneous way of representing it ?

Comment: IMHO yes, there's a problem. It's not valid. It's not even K&R.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch gcc doesn't compile this.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Exactly. I have tried on gcc and it does not compile this. Any special flags you are using ?

Comment: The weird thing is that this function appears in this form in most texts. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: It's incorrect C syntax. Don't believe evrything you read on the internet.

Comment: @PSkocik It even appears in the same form in [TCP/IP Illustrated](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6H9AxyFd0v0C&pg=PT658&lpg=PT658&dq=int+pr_usrreq(struct+socket+*so+,+int+req,+struct+mbuf+*m0+,+*m1+,+*m2);&source=bl&ots=b7gH4r8TdJ&sig=ielVqs9gxzo7sarVw_WGwFok-7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiezJikiLHXAhXDvI8KHcKkDscQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=int%20pr_usrreq(struct%20socket%20*so%20%2C%20int%20req%2C%20struct%20mbuf%20*m0%20%2C%20*m1%20%2C%20*m2)%3B&f=false)

Comment: @PSkocik Is this syntax possible in C++ ?

Comment: If you are interested in other online networking guides [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is a reasonable guide, and updated from time to time.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks

Answer (score 4):

From the text [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6H9AxyFd0v0C&pg=PT658&lpg=PT658&dq=int+pr_usrreq(struct+socket+%2Aso+,+int+req,+struct+mbuf+%2Am0+,+%2Am1+,+%2Am2);&source=bl&ots=b7gH4r8TdJ&sig=ielVqs9gxzo7sarVw_WGwFok-7w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiezJikiLHXAhXDvI8KHcKkDscQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=int%20pr_usrreq(struct%20socket%20%2Aso%20%2C%20int%20req%2C%20struct%20mbuf%20%2Am0%20%2C%20%2Am1%20%2C%20%2Am2)%3B&f=false) it appears that:

```
int pr_usrreq(struct socket *so, int req, struct mbuf *m0 , *m1 , *m2);
```

should actually be:

```
int pr_usrreq(struct socket *so, int req, struct mbuf *m0, struct mbuf* m1, struct mbuf *m2);
```

It's just a typo.

Comment: Yeah but this typo is present even in many well known books like TCP illustrated (as linked in the comments)

Comment: @ng.newbie That's why where is even a term for this kind of errors: "copy-paste errors". (Though it seems it is not as official as I thought - couldn't find an appropriate link in google...)

Comment: @ng.newbie that's true, but it _is_ obviously wrong. And the text says clearly: _The next three arguments (m0, m1, and m2) are differtent for each request. They are always passed as pointers to mbuf structures,..._

Comment: Probably then didn't have space on the text line to pasting all and instead of breaking the declaration in multiple lines they remove the two struct mbuf *.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a still-born hybrid between an ANSI prototype and a K&R function head. The link says `m0`, `m1`, and `m2` should be of type `struct mbuf*`. That needs to be written explicitly like so:

```
int pr_usrreq(struct socket *so , int req, struct mbuf *m0 , struct mbuf *m1 , struct mbuf *m2);
```

The form you presented is definitely incorrect.

In K&R style* the (by definition, prototype-less) declaration would be

```
int pr_usrreq();
```

and the function definition would start with

```
int pr_usrreq(so, req, m0, m1, m2) 
  struct socket *so; 
  int req;
  struct mbuf *m0, *m1, *m2; {
```

It looks like somebody got the erroneous "prototype" by incorrectly converting from the old form.

---

<sub>*The K&R style is deprecated in current C and not supported by any version of C++.</sub>